# PDO script with some errors

Tags: php, pdo, transactions

I have some problem with my script.
I receive this error: Fatal error: Cannot access empty property

The code is:

```
public function insertap()

{

    try 
     {
         //echo $_POST['tranzactie'].$_POST['tip'].$_POST['tip_loc'].$_SESSION['uid'];
            $stmt=$this->$dbh->beginTransaction();
            $sql="INSERT INTO `anunturi` (`tranzactie`, `tip`, `tip2`, `user`) VALUES (:tranz, :tip, :tip_loc, :user)" ;
            $stmt->prepare($sql);
            $data = array('tranz' => $_POST['tranzactie'], 'tip' => $_POST['tip'], 'tip_loc'=>$_POST['tip_loc'], 'user'=>$_SESSION['uid']);
            $stmt->execute($data);
            $stmt->commit();
     }
    catch (Exception $e)
    {
            $stmt->rollback();
            echo "A aparut o eroare";
    }

}
```

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
$data = array('tranz' => $_POST['tranzactie'], 'tip' => $_POST['tip'], 'tip_loc'=>$_POST['tip_loc'], 'user'=>$_SESSION['uid']);
```

to

```
$data = array(':tranz' => $_POST['tranzactie'], ':tip' => $_POST['tip'], ':tip_loc'=>$_POST['tip_loc'], ':user'=>$_SESSION['uid']);
```

Comment: You give me an ideea and now the script working...Thanks a lot

Comment: I'm glad I could give something back to the community. What was the exact issue?

Answer (score 0):

- This $dbh is unset so it becomes $this->null->beginTransaction().
- beginTransaction() returns a bool so $stmt becomes bool not PDOStatement

-

```
$stmt=$this->$dbh->beginTransaction();
```

Should probably be something like

```
$this->dbh->beginTransaction();
$sql = ...
$stmt = $this->dbh->prepare($sql);
```

Replace ... with your insert query.

- You don't need transactions for just one query.

Comment: Call to a member function prepare() on a non-object after I change it

Comment: @user2838459 yes beginTransaction returns a bool. You don't really need it for just one query.